# PHP - Displaying form input without re-displaying the form

Tags: php, forms

How do I echo the form input without having to re-display the form after validation? I can only display the input after the form. Here is the code I have

```
<?php
$postalCode = $_POST['postalCode'];
$postalCodeErr = "";
$postalCodeValidation = '/^[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]$/';
$postalCodeIsValid = false;
?>
<html>
<body>
    INT322 Lab 3-1
    <br />
    <br />
    <form name="lab3form" action="index.php" method="post">
        Postal Code:
        <input type="text" name="postalCode" value="<?php if(isset($postalCode)) echo $postalCode; ?>" />
        <?php
        if(($postalCode != "") && preg_match($postalCodeValidation, $postalCode)) {
            $postalCodeIsValid = true;
        }
        else {
            $postalCodeErr = "Invalid Postal Code";
        }
        if(isset($postalCode)) echo " $postalCodeErr";
        ?>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if($_POST['submit'] && $postalCodeIsValid) {
    echo "Postal Code: $postalCode";
}
?>
```

Comment: Submit the form to php via ajax, if it's valid, show your content, otherwise alert the user.

Answer (score 1):

How about wrapping your form in the `else` of `if($_POST['submit'] && $postalCodeIsValid) { ... } else { ... }`

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit'] && $postalCodeIsValid) {
    echo "Postal Code: $postalCode";
}
else {
    <form name="lab3form" action="index.php" method="post">
        Postal Code:
        <input type="text" name="postalCode" value="<?php if(isset($postalCode)) echo $postalCode; ?>" />
        <?php
        if(($postalCode != "") && preg_match($postalCodeValidation, $postalCode)) {
            $postalCodeIsValid = true;
        }
        else {
            $postalCodeErr = "Invalid Postal Code";
        }
        if(isset($postalCode)) echo " $postalCodeErr";
        ?>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
}
?>
```

**UPDATED ANSWER with full code:**

```
<html>
<body>
    INT322 Lab 3-1
    <br />
    <br />
    <?php 
        if(!empty($_POST['submit'])):
            $postalCode = $_POST['postalCode'];
            if(isValidPostalCode($postalCode)):
                echo "Postal Code: $postalCode";
            else:
                form($postalCode, true);
            endif;
        else:
            form();
        endif;
    ?>
</body>
</html>

<?php

function form($postalCode = null, $hasError = false) { ?>
    <form name="lab3form" action="postal.php" method="post">
        Postal Code:
        <input type="text" name="postalCode" value="<?php if(isset($postalCode)) echo $postalCode; ?>" />
        <?php if ($hasError): ?>
            <div class="error">Invalid Postal Code</div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
<?php }

function isValidPostalCode($postalCode) {
    $postalCodeValidation = '/^[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]$/';
    return !empty($postalCode) && preg_match($postalCodeValidation, $postalCode);
}
?>
```

Please note that your regular expression only works with postal codes such as `A1B2C3` - I'm not sure if this is the behavior you want.

Comment: I have tried this however the form is still displayed and the results are not echoed

Comment: I have not tried the updated version, I have solved the problem with another method